# Unity Android Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I am trying to build from Unity to my Android device, but i keep getting this error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
/Users/jespermansa/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.3/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "/Users/jespermansa/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.chartboost.sdk.unity:eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage:com.android.vending.billing:com.google.unity:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.onesignal.onesignalsdk:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:com.unity.purchasing:android.support.customtabs:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:com.onesignal:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.clearcut:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.gcm:com.google.android.gms.iid:com.google.android.gms.location:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/CropLib/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GoogleAIDL/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GooglePlay/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/OneSignalConfig/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.4.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/cardview-v7-23.4.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/common/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/customtabs-23.4.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-wrapper-7.9.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/onesignal-unity/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-ads-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-ads-lite-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-base-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-basement-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-clearcut-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-gass-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-gcm-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-iid-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-location-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-tasks-10.0.1/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-v4-23.4.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-v4-24.0.0/res" -S "/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-vector-drawable-23.4.0/res"

stderr[
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_material.xml:48: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/abc_alert_dialog_material for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:100: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:fontFamily from <Button>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:fontFamily from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:56: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:fontFamily from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v16 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment for configuration v16.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:136: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:fontFamily from <Button>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:112: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:112: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:59: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:fontFamily from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0/res/layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v16 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment for configuration v16.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:60: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <ImageView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:30: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_lines.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_lines.xml:77: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_lines.xml:96: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_lines.xml:64: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_lines.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_lines.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/notification_template_lines for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_media.xml:43: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <include>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_media.xml:33: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource dk.jespermansa.numfeud13:layout/notification_template_media for configuration v17.
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_part_chronometer.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <Chronometer>
/Users/jespermansa/UnityProjects/Numfeud_CrossPlatform/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-23.1.1/res/layout/notification_template_part_chronometer.xml: note: usin<message truncated>
```

I am not sure why, I have previously done this with out any errors... Hope someone can see through the woods and help.

Ane help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a duplicated library, for what I see in the log it seems to be android-support-v4, look for android-support-v4 or support-v4 in your project, you should have at least 2 of them, delete them until you only have 1 android-support-v4.